# My Raspberry pi doesnt capture frames even though pi cam is detected in index 0

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, rtsp, libcamera

I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with Pi camera module v3, I'm trying to launch an RTSP stream server that streams camera feed, I've been using [this](https://github.com/bpradana/zephyr) RTSP library, when I run the server script :

```
import cv2
from zephyr import Stream

if __name__ == "__main__":
  stream = Stream(
    url="rtsp://localhost:8554/test",
    resolution=(1280, 720),
    fps=30,
    bitrate="2M"
  )

  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    stream.send(frame)
```

I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/testserver1.py", line 15, in <module>
    stream.send(frame)
  File "/home/pi/innov/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zephyr/stream/stream.py", line 174, in send
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, self.resolution)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4062: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

even though my camera is detected :

```
(venv) pi@YassinePi:~ $ libcamera-still --list-cameras
Available cameras
-----------------
0 : imx708 [4608x2592 10-bit RGGB] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a)
    Modes: 'SRGGB10_CSI2P' : 1536x864 [120.13 fps - (768, 432)/3072x1728 crop]
                             2304x1296 [56.03 fps - (0, 0)/4608x2592 crop]
                             4608x2592 [14.35 fps - (0, 0)/4608x2592 crop]
```

I've tried changing the index from 1,-1,2 didn't work

I think it may be because this code is designed for desktop computers, or I didn't install the required packages correctly

For the second reason since I don't have experience with Raspbian OS, I reinstalled the OS and installed the packages all over again, still doesn't work.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Or there is an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Your camera is sending you 4608x2592 10-bit Bayer codes (RGGB).  You are attempting to send those frames directly out to a stream that you SAID is 1280x720 30fps.  You are going to have to convert the frames to the output format you want.  I don't think OpenCV knows how to do that.

Comment: Does this help? Put variable in parameter `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)`

Comment: didn't work sorry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/testserver1.py", line 12, in <module>
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'VideoCapture'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
>  - VideoCapture() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)
>  - Argument 'index' is required to be an integer
>  - VideoCapture() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)

Comment: Any idea how i can adapt these frames ?

Comment: Try `print(frame.shape)` immediately after reading the frame to see what you are getting.

Comment: I get Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Ok, that means you didn't read a frame of data (i.e. a picture) at all from your camera - your frame is empty. Are you using a standard Camera Module 3? I am unsure what cameras OpenCV's VideoCapture supports - have you tried using `rpicam-vid -t 10000 -o test.h264` to record a 10s video and play it back with `vlc test.h264`? If that works, maybe you can run `rpicam-vid` to send frames to your Python app instead of using OpenCV VideoCapture.

Comment: it returns rpicam-vid : command not found. I guess It's because the rpicam doesn't support camera module 3 neither does opencv. I guess i have to buy a pi camera module 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Have a read here https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html

Comment: OpenCV expects proper V4L devices. libcamera does not do that. libcamera is special. you need to use libcamera instead of opencv to read from your camera.

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67321053/2836621 What I am suggesting is that you use libcamera instead of raspivid to read uncompressed frames from the camera and then pipe them into your Python script which can read them and process them. It just reads with a standard `read()` system call rather than a VideoCapture `read()`.

Comment: what you re saying is to run this command ? raspivid -rf rgb  -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 30 -o - | ffmpeg ...     i get [NULL @ 0x55cd9dc590] Unable to find a suitable output format for '...'
...: Invalid argument

Comment: Sorry, I do not have your camera else I would work it out for you. I am trying to push you in the right direction, but doing it blind. The error message seems to mean your camera cannot produce RGB format so you need to read the link I sent you and find what formats it can produce then try those - maybe you'll need `raspivid -rf yuv420...` or `raspivid -rf mjpeg...`

Comment: when i ran this it worked fine : import cv2
from picamera2 import Picamera2

`# Grab images as numpy arrays and leave everything else to OpenCV.

picam2 = Picamera2()
print(1)
picam2.configure(picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"format": 'XRGB8888', "size": (640, 480)}))
print(2)
picam2.start()
print(3)
while True:
    print(4)
    im = picam2.capture_array()
    print(5)
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(grey.shape)
    cv2.imshow("Camera", im)
    cv2.waitKey(1)` (after installing picamera2 without venv)

Comment: but this : doesnt work `mport cv2
from zephyr import Stream
from picamera2 import Picamera2
if __name__ == "__main__":
  stream = Stream(
    url="rtsp://localhost:8554/test",
    resolution=(1280, 720),
    fps=30,
    bitrate="2M"
  )
  picam2 = Picamera2()
  picam2.configure(picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"format": 'XRGB8888', "size": (640, 480)}))
  picam2.start()
  while True:
    im = picam2.capture_array()
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, frame = grey.read()
    stream.send(frame)` it returns no module named picamera2

Comment: i used the virtual env because i cant install zephyr rtsp librarry without it, and when i use it im unable to install picamera2 within venv

Comment: Please don't put code in comments where it is unformatted and difficult to read. Click [edit] instead and format it properly in there where folks expect to find it and can read it without going through a bunch of comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV expects proper V4L devices. `libcamera` does not do that. `libcamera` is special. You need to use `libcamera` instead of OpenCV to read from your camera.

[There is at least one library that provides libcamera access in Python](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2).